# Python Feature Engineering Patients Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi I'm trying to feature engineer a Patient dataset from movement level to patient level.

Original df looks like this:

[image]

**Conditions:**
1) Create `Last Platelets Change` col - For `CaseNo` that encounters the `Category` value 'ICU', take the `Platelets` change before 'ICU' value (189-180 for CaseNo 1), else take the latest `Platelets` change (256-266 for CaseNo 2).
2) Create `Platelets_Pattern` col - For `CaseNo` that encounters the `Category` value 'ICU', pivot all the `Platelets` values from start till before 'ICU' value. Else pivot all `Platelets` values from start to end.
3)Create `Last Platelets Count` col - For `CaseNo` that encounters the `Category` value 'ICU', take the last `Platelets` value before 'ICU' encounter. Else take the last `Platelets` value.

**Expected Outcome**:

[image]

How do I go about this in Python? The 'ICU' value part is tripping me up.

**Code for df**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CaseNo':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                    'Movement_Sequence_No':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                    'Movement_Start_Date':['2020-02-09 22:17:00','2020-02-10 17:19:41','2020-02-17 08:04:19',
                                           '2020-02-18 11:22:52','2020-02-12 23:00:00','2020-02-24 10:26:35',
                                           '2020-03-03 17:50:00','2020-03-17 08:24:19'],
                    'Movement_End_Date':['2020-02-10 17:19:41','2020-02-17 08:04:19','2020-02-18 11:22:52',
                                         '2020-02-25 13:55:37','2020-02-24 10:26:35','2020-03-03 17:50:00',
                                         '2222-12-31 23:00:00','2020-03-18 18:50:00'],
                    'Category':['A','A','ICU','A','B','B','B','B'],
                    'RequestDate':['2020-02-10 16:00:00','2020-02-16 13:04:20','2020-02-18 07:11:11','2020-02-21 21:30:30',
                                   '2020-02-13 22:00:00','NA','2020-03-15 09:40:00','2020-03-18 15:10:10'],
                    'Platelets':['180','189','190','188','328','NA','266','256'],
                    'Age':['65','65','65','65','45','45','45','45']})
```

Comment: Can you share  sample dataset and not images? You can copy-paste `df.head(N).to_dict()` where `N` is the number of sample.

Comment: I've added df sample dataset code in at the bottom of original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `groupby` to group the dataframe on `CaseNo` and then `apply` a custom function on each group to produce the expected values.

For each group, you should first find the index of the row before a ICU category if any to find the list of Platelets to process (do not forget to remove `NA` values). Then just do trivial operations to compute the results and return a `Series` per group:

```
def process(x):
    age = x.at[x.first_valid_index(), 'Age']  # store age
    # compute index of last row before Category ICU (or get None)
    ix = x[x['Category'].shift(-1) == 'ICU'].first_valid_index()
    # get list of non NA Platelets before ix (get all if ix is None)
    platelets = [i for i in x.loc[:ix,'Platelets'] if i != 'NA']
    # initialize change and count to np.nan (in case less than 2 Platelets)
    change = count = np.nan
    try:
        count = platelets[-1]
        change = int(platelets[-1]) - int(platelets[-2])
    except IndexError:   # if less than 2 platelets, values will stay at NaN
        pass
    return pd.Series({'Last Platelets Change': change,
              'Platelets_Pattern': ','.join(platelets),
              'Last Platelets Count': count,
              'Age': age})

result = df.groupby('CaseNo').apply(process).reset_index()
```

With you sample `df`, it gives as expected:

```
   CaseNo  Last Platelets Change Platelets_Pattern Last Platelets Count Age
0       1                      9           180,189                  189  65
1       2                    -10       328,266,256                  256  45
```

Comment: could you pls explain the function in more details? esp the variables being declared. code works but having hard time understanding thorougly.

Comment: if I had 5 columns that emulate 'Platelets', how will the code be modified to apply to all of these 5 rows? Will a for loop to iterate through 5 of these cols on top of your prev code suffice?